# How to press back button to exit app in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have a bit of issues that would need your help.
I have two screens

1. SplashScreen
2. HomeScreen

Currently when on press back button it still return to SplashScreen
I want App exit when on press back button HomeScreen.

Please kindly suggest me any ideas or provide me a sample code to implement this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Open your Login Screen from Splash using **pushReplacement**

```
 Navigator.pushReplacement(
      context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Login()));
```

> **Exit Application**

**For iOS**

`SystemNavigator.pop()`:     Does NOT WORK

`exit(0)`: Works but Apple may SUSPEND YOUR APP because it's against Apple Human Interface guidelines to exit the app programmatically.

**For Android**
`SystemNavigator.pop()`:
Works and is the RECOMMENDED way of exiting the app.

`exit(0):`
Also works but it's NOT RECOMMENDED as it terminates the Dart VM process immediately and user may think that the app just got crashed.

Comment: `SystemNavigator.pop();` worked perfectly

Comment: @Petro does it work for both Android and iOS?

Comment: @Falady there is no back button in iOS

Comment: @DeepakRor Oh i forgot about that. Does SystemNavigator.pop() still work if iOS users swipe their screen to exit the app?